# Just Another Sudoku for PSE

Tags: logical-deduction, no-computers, grid-deduction, sudoku

[image: Sudoku]

---

<sup>*Crafted with love for PSE, <3*</sup>

Comment: Sorry, a fatal mistake on previous image ><

Comment: I like the lettering.

Comment: what lettering? @hexomino (sorry for not getting the pun if any)

Comment: @OmegaKrypton The shape the numbers spell out is PSE.

Comment: ah lmao how come i didnt notice? thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this is the solution

> [image]

There isn't any particularly hard deduction here but if anybody has any queries, I can address them in the question.

Comment: Correct, good job!